# can't feed to database table via eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i am new to laravel.I have a project table in my database and i created a eloquent model using `php artisan make:model project;`

it created the following codes in project.php page

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class project extends Model
{
    //
}
```

when i attempt to feed data in my projects table laravel is giving me the error like

```
Route::get('/', function () 
 {
        $project = new project;  
    $project->name = 'Leonardo Da Vinci';

    $project->save();   
    return View::make('welcome');
 });
```

> class project not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that your `project` model has a namespace.
Either you import your model class on top of your `routes.php`:

```
use App\project
```

or use the full qualified name directly in code:

```
$project = new App\project;
```

> I recommend to use upper camel case syntax for your class name like the whole framework do `App\Project`